# Cocoa Touch Frameworks - Bitcode support

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, frameworks, bitcode

I'm building a framework for my company. I have a workspace with two projects inside, the Cocoa Touch Framework and the Example app. I've a Run Script, that runs every time I build my framework, that builds simulator and device version and then lipo them to create fat framework. All of this is distributed via Cocoapods, so I've set the `vendored_frameworks` attribute on the podspec and so on. Everything installs correctly in other projects, except for one thing : it's impossible to archive projects because the framework does not contain bitcode. These are my xcodebuild command (in the run script) :

```
# Build both device and simulator versions for iOS
xcodebuild BITCODE_GENERATION_MODE=bitcode -project "${PROJECT_DIR}/${PROJECT_NAME}.xcodeproj" -derivedDataPath "${BUILD_DIR}" -scheme "${PROJECT_NAME}" -sdk iphonesimulator -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone X' clean build

xcodebuild BITCODE_GENERATION_MODE=bitcode -project "${PROJECT_DIR}/${PROJECT_NAME}.xcodeproj" -derivedDataPath "${BUILD_DIR}" -scheme "${PROJECT_NAME}" -sdk iphoneos clean build
```

I set the build configuration to Release, so it does not use Debug. However, always the same problem : no way to archive an app with this framework inside.
Do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

There are **2 options:**

### 1.Try this to build your framework wth bitcode:

```
xcodebuild BITCODE_GENERATION_MODE=bitcode OTHER_CFLAGS="-fembed-bitcode" -target "${PROJECT_NAME}" ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO -configuration ${CONFIGURATION} -sdk iphoneos BUILD_DIR="${BUILD_DIR}" BUILD_ROOT="${BUILD_ROOT}" clean build
xcodebuild BITCODE_GENERATION_MODE=bitcode OTHER_CFLAGS="-fembed-bitcode" -target "${PROJECT_NAME}" -configuration ${CONFIGURATION} -sdk iphonesimulator ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO BUILD_DIR="${BUILD_DIR}" BUILD_ROOT="${BUILD_ROOT}" clean build
```

### 2.Or you opt to disable bitcode in your application